# invalid procedure call or argument vba when populating ComboBox

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have 2 excel files and in main excel file I have 2 comboBox elements, one of them should be populate from another worksheet and 2nd from another workbook and when I'm trying to populate this combobox by using data from another workbook like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").ComboBox23.List = Sheets("Modification").Range("C2:C55").Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").ComboBox24.List = GetObject(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\resourcetracker.xls").Sheets("Resources").Range("A2:A22").Value 
End Sub
```

I can get data from another worksheet in main excel file, but line where i'm opening another workbook gives me an error

> Invalid procedure call or argument (Run-time Error 5)

Can someone help with to understand what i'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetObject` is not the right way to open another `WorkBook`

Try this instead

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").ComboBox23.List = Sheets("Modification").Range("C2:C55").Value
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\resourcetracker.xls")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").ComboBox24.List = wb.Sheets("Resources").Range("A2:A22").Value
    wb.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: this way gives me another error -   Run time Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error” at moment of "Set wb ... "

Comment: Add this before it - `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path & "\resourcetracker.xls"` then look at your debug window. Does that file exist in that location?

Comment: It's funny; I have these 2 file in one folder ~ "C:\Users\User1\Documents\Excel files\" and my idea with ThisWorkbook.Path was just to save time if files would be moved; after I replaced it with full address everything works; and ThisWorkbook.Path returns exactly this part "C:\Users\User1\Documents\Excel files"

Comment: also can I add If statement to it to make it check if this workbook is already opened, or it's a important part of the logic in excel to open it first ?

Comment: Because I used `Add` instead of `Open` it doesnt matter if it's already open or not.